# How to know authenticated email of an user who authenticated with his google account for my app

Tags: node.js, google-api, google-calendar-api, google-oauth, google-api-nodejs-client

I am integrating google authentication for my app for creating calender events.

```
const {google} = require('googleapis');

const SCOPES = ['https://www.googleapis.com/auth/calendar','https://www.googleapis.com/auth/userinfo.email']
```

I have used the above scopes in authentication and generated the url and sent to the client. Authentication got success and i am able to receive code and generating token.

But with the code, I need the authenticated user's email, whoever signed in. Is there any way/example to know how to get user's email?. I searched in google for finding solution. But i didn't get that. Help me to know about this.

Answer (score -1):

After you have received the token, you need to make a HTTP request to the `userinfo` endpoint using that token to get the required user info.

You can get the url for that endpoint from the discovery document which can be found at https://accounts.google.com/.well-known/openid-configuration.

The current url to get user info is https://openidconnect.googleapis.com/v1/userinfo.

Answer (score -1):

If you do a [calendar get](https://developers.google.com/calendar/v3/reference/calendars/get?apix_params=%7B%22calendarId%22%3A%22primary%22%7D) on the users primary calendar.  All users have a primary calendar

### request

> GET https://www.googleapis.com/calendar/v3/calendars/primary

### response

```
{
 "kind": "calendar#calendar",
 "etag": "\"JWPyaEfg9X1jMhlHCcI4tl2h6uo/AxePbI13h8-KuIOLek\"",
 "id": "xxxx@gmail.com",
 "summary": "xxx@gmail.com",
 "timeZone": "Europe/Copenhagen",
 "conferenceProperties": {
  "allowedConferenceSolutionTypes": [
   "eventHangout"
  ]
 }
}
```

Both Id and summary will be the users email address. By doing it this way you will not need to request the `https://www.googleapis.com/auth/userinfo.email` scope

## Node guesss

Note: I am not a node.js developer this is a wild guess you will have to work this out

```
function listEvents(auth) {
  const calendar = google.calendar({version: 'v3', auth});
  calendar.about.get({
    calendarId: 'primary'
  }, (err, res) => {
    if (err) return console.log('The API returned an error: ' + err);
    const results = res;
    if (results ) {
      console.log(results.id);
    } else {
      console.log('No upcoming events found.');
    }
  });
```

Comment: @DalmTo, what is the request format for this GET API?

Comment: I am not a Node.js developer i gave you a guess at some code you will really have to work out the call yourself.   Not all the methods are documented for every language.   If you follow the quickstart you should get an idea of how these calls are built up https://developers.google.com/calendar/quickstart/nodejs

Comment: @PolaiahBodeddula did this help you did you get it working?

Comment: @Dalm To It didn't help me.

Comment: But i tried with the below API. It gave me the details.

https://oauth2.googleapis.com/tokeninfo

GET Request with query params(access_token)